# Poor performance while opening a large number of tooltips using Leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet, tooltip

The objective is to display about 3000 tooltips when the user ticks a checkbox in control layer.

At the moment, I am binding each tooltip to a feature of geoJSON layer during the initialization. I am listening to the add and remove events, and accordingly opening and closing tooltip. However, it is taking about 20 seconds for all the tooltips to get displayed.

The code snippet is as follows:

```
function bind_tooltip(layer,val){
layer.bindTooltip(val.toString(), {permanent: true, direction: 'top'});
layer
    .on('remove', function(){layer.closeTooltip();})
    .on('add', function(){layer.openTooltip();});
}
```

Could someone suggest me a better method to solve this problem? Thank you!

Comment: Sure I'll suggest one. How about not trying to display 3000 elements at once?

Comment: What is the purpose of displaying every tooltip at once? This is not what tooltips are typically used for.

Comment: I want to display certain numbers corresponding to each feature of geoJSON together.

Answer (score 1):

By profiling the code for my use case, I realized that a significant amount of cumulative time (for the large number of tooltips) was being taken to calculate `tooltipWidth` and `tooltipHeight` inside `Tooltip._setPosition()` source code function.

I redefined the `_setPosition()` function by using `L.class.include()` to hard-code values for the `tooltipWidth` and `tooltipHeight`, and set `direction = 'right'`. While this probably isn't the best solution, it improved the speed considerably.

If there is a better solution, kindly share it. Thanks!